# How to use numba in parallel for varying length lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

I have a function which already is njitted and returns a list of uint32 with varying lengths.

```
@numba.njit()
def inner_function(A: numba.float32[:]) -> List[int]:
    # ...
```

That function is called in a loop a large number of times, which could be parallelized since there is no data dependency.

But since the function returns varying lengths a preallocated array can't be used.

What i currently have is a sequential approach using numbas typed list like that

```
@numba.njit()
def looping_function(A: numba.float32[:,:]) -> List[List[int]]:
    result = List()
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        tmp = inner_function(A[i])
        result.append(tmp)
    return result
```

Is there maybe a way to initialize my the result list (or any other datastructure) in such a way that I can index it instead of appending to it like that:

```
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def looping_function(A: numba.float32[:,:]):
    result = ???
    for i in numba.prange(A.shape[0]):
        tmp = inner_function(A[i])
        result[i] = tmp
    return result
```

Comment: What's wrong with appending?

Comment: I can not do that in parallel without running into raceconditions, but the order of elements has to be kept.

Comment: Lists are generally not efficient, even in Numba (especially when they are converted from/to reflected list). Other data structure can be more efficient regarding what you plan to do with them. Do you plan to add/remove list items or the structure is left unchanged over time? Do you know the size of the sub-list easily? Can you tell us more about what you want to do with such data structure?

Comment: The data wont be mutated going forward. The size can not be known, and will change depending on the argument. But giving an upper bound might be possible.

Comment: I guess I could allocate an array with that upper bound and store the length elsewhere, but that would be a huge waste of space since that's way more than the average

Comment: But how much? Can you share anything about the dimensions? Arrays are very efficient, it's often fine to over-allocate a little if memory remains reasonable.

Comment: The number of iterations can go into the millions and the length of the sublists is going to be worst case in the hundred-thousands. But mostly only on of those ist that large, the other ris then in the ten-thousands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it's not very satisfying but works well enough for my usecase.
This preallocates as list of lists with a placeholder 0 to ensure type inference.
Then I can remove the placeholder and extend as needed.

```
@numba.njit(parallel=True)#,forceobj=True)
def outer(i):
    a = numba.typed.List([numba.typed.List([0]) for _ in range(i)])
    for i in numba.prange(i):
        a[i].pop()
        a[i].extend(inner(i))
    return a
```